# CSS-only Accordion Gaps

Tags: html, css, accordion, codepen

I use a simple CSS-only accordion for our terms and conditions to hide and show clauses with **checkboxes** and the **transform** property.  However, when updating this info, there are suddenly large, inconsistent gaps between bullet points.  It occurs where the dropdown content is longer than three paragraphs and each gap varies in height.

What is the best solution that uses the least amount of code to fix this using **ONLY** using CSS?

***Absolutely no jQuery, Javascript, or other external library can be used.**
The full code can be found here:
[codepen.io/makecodenotwar/pen/dmXpjJ](https://codepen.io/makecodenotwar/pen/dmXpjJ)

SAMPLE: HTML structure of one bullet point (full code at codepen):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <i></i>
    <h5><span>►</span>Payment Clause</h5>
    <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

SAMPLE CSS

```
p {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li i {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-6px, 0);
}
ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
}
ul li i:before {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li i:after {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes flipdown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateX(8deg);
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotateX(6deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe add `<br>`break ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hide the accordion items

Your items are not visible, but they are still there.

Try to add this in your code:

```
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks @claudio , I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a very long time since I worked on HTML or CSS, but did you see this [example](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-only-accordion/) already? Please forgive me if you have.